# Error with Woocommerce short description in category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the code I'm using and it appears to work correctly when log in

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt')) {
    function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
    {
        $content_length = 10;
        global $post;
        $content = $post->brief_description;
        $wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
        if (count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
            array_pop($wordarray);
            array_push($wordarray, '...');
            $content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
            $content = force_balance_tags($content);
        endif;
        echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
    }
}
```

When I logout and check the page, the first product in each category doesn't show the short description I added, although it appears when I'm login.

Is there a problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

How it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdwP8.jpg

How it look when logout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KasgW.jpg